# Блок (div) не растягивается дальше размера окна браузера.

Tags: html, css

Не сочтите за рекламу, вот страница: http://jakeroid.com/. Уменьшите окно браузера в ширину, что бы оно стало меньше 1024рх. Прокрутите горизонтальную полосу прокрутки в право. Верхний черный блок не растянулся до конца экрана.

[image]

Можно ли это как то исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проще всего.

```
#top{
 min-width: 1024px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это делает top не меньше 1024px. А можно как то сделать, что бы было как в режиме full-screen - от левого конца браузера и до правого?

Comment: ничего не понял. если добавить min-width то это не даст диву уменьшаться меньше чем на 1024 пикселей, но если разрешение экрана будет больше, то он прекрасно растянется до конца

Comment: Можно ли убрать вот этот промежуток?
http://clck.ru/1-Y8i

Comment: style.css 208 строка `#top_content`,  `left:25px` заменить на `padding-left:50px`

Comment: Осталось так же. Все равно вам огромное спасибо!